# DialogFlow : travelling bot Departure and returning date issue

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created an agent about travel.

For example :

- 1st human question : I want to go to Nepal
- The bot answers correctly with: what is your departure date
- Human answers : 9th of April
- etc.

I need to ask for the date of return, and I don't know how to create answers or intent correctly to make the bot understand the difference between departure date and date of return.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Intents represent *what the user says* and not how you interpret it.

You can keep track of where in the conversation you are, and thus what the date represents, by storing the state in a [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts).